# mysql wrong select output

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I created table using command:

```
CREATE TABLE genre(
    genre_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Then I filled table with data using command:

```
load data infile 'D:/MySQL/.../genres.txt' into table genre(name);
```

There is one record on every line.

Problem occured when I tried to print content of table into terminal using command:

```
select * from genre;
```

Output:

```
 +----------+--------------+
 | genre_id | name         |
 +----------+--------------+
 |       1 | alternative
   | 2 | blues
 |   3 | classic
 |   4 | country
   | 5 | dance
 |   6 | electro
    |7 | folk
     | | pop
     | | rap
    |0 | jazz
  | 11 | latino
   |12 | opera
     | | r&b
  | 14 | reagge
    |5 | rock
 |       16 | metal        |
   |
 +----------+--------------+
```

(vertical bars are printed wrong too)

Does anyone know why is output of first column printed wrong? I am mysql beginner so sorry if it is a dumb question.

File content:

```
alternative
blues
classic
country
dance
electro
folk
pop
rap
jazz
latino
opera
r&b
reagge
rock
metal
```

Comment: Looks like your input file has white-spaces. Can you try running SELECT genre_id, TRIM(name) AS name.

Comment: SELECT genre_id, TRIM(name) AS name - same output

Comment: Please show the contents of your file (first 10 lines)

Comment: Does the table already have rows in it?

Comment: Someone edited output code. | characters are on wrong position too.

Comment: What happens if you run `LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`? I think it is a Windows file with a '\r\n' terminator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

The column `genre_id` is auto-incremented.  So, when a row is inserted into the table, the column gets a value.  It is as simple as that.

You appear to have rows with no genre_id.  That is not possible.  The column is declared as an integer and it cannot take on a `NULL` value.  So, you would see *some* value for every inserted row.

The conclusion is that the rows that look like they are missing `genre_id` really are not separate rows at all.  Instead, they are single rows that have embedded newline or carriage return characters that are messing up the output.  If you are using a Unix-based system, you can use `od` (octal dump) to see the contents of the file.  There is probably some correct line terminator that will fix the problem.